# ASP MVC action parameter binding depending on culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, culture, action-filter

I have a multi cultural website in ASP.Net MVC with an action filter which take care to set the current culture of the application depending on several criterias (database, cookie, etc).

My problem is that the user can submit a form with multiple inputs of type double.
The post occured in an action with a parameter binded on the form containing one property by input. When the double contains a comma (French culture for example), the binding does not occur because the filter is called after the binding...

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Might be usefull blogpost: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I saw this method and at the end it is what I did even if it is not perfect in my case since the globalization occurs AFTER the binding in a filter...So I had to move some code I did not want to.